# Close window C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a window that has a button and the button is just supposed to create a window and then delete it.
The variable `online` is initialized to false.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ZeitenZeiger zeiten = new ZeitenZeiger();
    if (!online)
    {
        zeiten.Show();
        zeiten.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        online = true;
    }
    else
    {
        zeiten.Close();
        online = false;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You create a new instance of `zeiten` every time the button is clicked.

So your `.Close` call calls another `zeiten` than your `.Show` opened.

Solve this by declaring `zeiten` on class level, and avoid closing it, instead hide it:

```cs
ZeitenZeiger zeiten = new ZeitenZeiger();
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!online)
    {
        zeiten.Show();
        zeiten.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    online = true;
    }
    else
    {
        zeiten.Hide();  // <-- Change close to hide!
        online = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that after you have called `.Close()` for a form, you will no longer be able to call `.Show()`. I suspect that the OP wants to be able to show and hide the same form repeatedly, which will not be possible if it is closed.

Comment: You are right, he should use ``.Hide()`` instead of close - I change the code - thank you